# Distance matrix (nearest neighbour) with polygons

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I would like to calculate the closest distance between polygons in the same layer. The "distance matrix" tool only accept point layers.

Is there a (easy) way to calculate the distance between edges and edges ?

I work with qgis 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Virtual Layer is acceptable, here is an example:

```
SELECT     a.id AS Id_1, 
           b.id AS Id_2, 
           round(st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry), 3) AS Distance
FROM       your_polygons_layer AS a
CROSS JOIN your_polygons_layer AS b
ON         a.id <> b.id
```

- `your_polygons_layer`: layer name as imported
- `id`: any unique id field in `your_polygons_layer`

---

[EDIT] To delete duplicates:

```
SELECT     a.id AS Id_1, 
                b.id AS Id_2, 
                round(st_distance(a.geometry, b.geometry), 3) AS Distance
FROM       your_polygons_layer AS a
CROSS JOIN your_polygons_layer AS b
ON         a.id <> b.id
GROUP BY   concat(min(a.id, b.id), ' ', max(a.id, b.id))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kazuhito! I have tested and it works, but the distance between two polygons is writen two times (i.e. Id_1 with Id_2  AND Id_2 with Id_1).  A possibility to delete duplicates pairs ? I expected a matrix with n*(n-1)/2 lines.

Comment: Thanks @Volta and sorry about that. Will you test the latter syntax? (I have not yet had time to test it with data).